# what is the best method to check that multiple values are empty using jq?

Tags: jq

I'm trying to get a boolean that show me if any value are not empty with jq.

is possible that `jq 'if .a and .b =!'` return true or false ? any exit code maybe ?

empty:

```
| jq '.a , .b' 
[]
[]
```

Comment: What do you mean *empty*? Include an input and output example

Comment: jq '.a , .b' 
[]
[]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will suggest a solution to the kind of problem you have in mind:

```
jq -n '{a:[1],b:[1]} | any(.a, .b; . == [])'
false
```